# Create new raster from both overlapping and non-overlapping values of two other rasters in R

Tags: raster, r, reclassify

I am having trouble figuring out the best way to create a new raster from values in two separate rasters.  Some solutions involve creating stacks or bricks, others do not.

Here is an example:

## First raster is **"propSummPCPmod4"**

### Determine frequency of values

```
freq(propSummPCPmod4)

 value    count
```

[1,]     1  1417084

[2,]     3  9103585

[3,]    NA 14535331

## Second raster is **"propWintPCPmod4"**

### Determine frequency of values

```
freq(propWintPCPmod4)

 value    count
```

[1,]     2   241512

[2,]     3 10279157

[3,]    NA 14535331

### create a brick and plot both rasters side by side

```
brick1 <- brick(propSummPCPmod4, propWintPCPmod4)
plot(brick1, col=terrain.colors(255))
```

[image: plot of raster brick]

The plot shows that values of **1** from "propSummPCPmod4" [layer 1] and values of 2 from "propWintPCPmod4" [layer 2] do not overlap.

I want to a create a new raster and to employ the **"1"** values from propSummPCPmod4, the **"2"** values from propWintPCPmod4, and to have all other values represented by **"3" or NA**.  (NA values are outside the boundaries of the original source rasters)

I tried merge, cvr, overlay, and mask but couldn't get a satisfactory result.

Answer (score 1):

Your example was not reproduceble so I tryed to create a small set imitating your data. 
If I understood right, ou can do:

```
`library(raster)
propSummPCPmod4 <- raster(matrix(c(1,3,3,1,3,3,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),4,4))
propWintPCPmod4 <- raster(matrix(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, NA,2,3,3,2,2,2,2,3),4,4))
newraster <- raster(matrix(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA, NA),4,4))

summer_indices <- which(propSummPCPmod4[] == 1)
winter_indices <- which(propWintPCPmod4[] == 2)
newraster[summer_indices] <- 1
newraster[winter_indices] <- 2
newraster[is.na(newraster[])] <- 3
plot(newraster)`
```

propSummPCPmod4 and propWintPCPmod4

[image][image]

newraster

[image]

Comment: I added a reproducible example to clarify my question.  Does your suggestion still apply?  I haven't used the "which" function from the raster package.  Thanks

Comment: I ran your code using a new blank raster (same structure as the originals outlined above).  The newraster doesn't plot as expected.  https://photos.app.goo.gl/dgUPvCQzBzG6D64f7

Comment: check the edit I made on my answer and see if this is what you need

Comment: I tried again using your code @MarujoRe and it worked!  There had been a small formatting mistake in my new new raster code  The result looks way better now.  However, values of "3" and "NA" are not differentiated.  See https://photos.app.goo.gl/oFBggKnaqmPvpF5L6   
I tried this modified version of your code but it didn't work:  
```summer_indicesV3 <- which(propSummPCPmod4[] == 1,3)  
winter_indicesV3 <- which(propWintPCPmod4[] == 2,3)  
newrasterV3[summer_indices] <- 1  
newrasterV3[winter_indices] <- 2  
newrasterV3[winter_indices] <- 3```  
Sorry to pester you, it’s very close now!

Answer (score 1):

Try to separate which are not NA and which are value 3

```
summer_indices <- which(propSummPCPmod4[] == 1,3)

summer_notNA <- which(!is.na(propSummPCPmod4[]))

newraster[summer_notNA] <- 3

winter_indices <- which(propWintPCPmod4[] == 2,3) 

winter_notNA <- which(!is.na(propWintPCPmod4[]))

newraster[winter_notNA] <- 3

newraster[summer_indices] <- 1 

newraster[winter_indices] <- 2
```

Comment: That should have worked @MarujoRe.  There seems to be something wrong with the "3" values, however.  I tried trouble shooting and it happens right after the summer indices are added to the new raster.  This plot has both summer and winter indices.  https://photos.app.goo.gl/yidQmSUZo9XT6fPm8   You can see that value "3" is only at the top of the map.  All of North America should be value 3, except cells that are values 1 or 2.  NA values are only those outside the continent but within the raster extent (corresponds with the oceans).  Like this https://photos.app.goo.gl/rG3L1J2REwrjvuM57

Comment: I uploaded the two source rasters to make things easier.  I think the two reproducible example you created should work, but maybe there’s something we’re missing from the data structure.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1HW_uVi8Vpm96sJ7sptaoeQSYyQXzNrc0 and https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Eqt46I3xka01_CYAI6mcnzRXM7Efs7iD

Comment: ohh sorry i have made the wrong atribution. I have edited the message. Now it should work. if it doesn't I will download your raster when I get home.

Comment: That worked!  I am just learning the raster package and building my R skills.  I needed this solution for my work and I learned new coding functions and syntax too!  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, I would use min value between both rasters using `overlay()` function:

(reproducible example)

```
library(raster)

r <- raster()

r1 <- setValues(r,3)

r2 <- setValues(r,3)

r1[1:20000] <- 1
r2[44800:64800] <- 2

plot(stack(r1,r2), col=terrain.colors(255))
```

[image]

Minimum between both rasters:

```
r3 <- overlay(r1,r2,fun=min)

plot(r3)
```

[image]

If you want to keep the other values as `NA`:

```
r3[r3==3] <- NA

plot(r3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @aldo_tapia!  I will try this solution next week and see if works for me.  Initially I had ran some trials with the overlay function but couldn't get them to provide the result I need.